# windows print service

Tags: windows-server-2008, print-server

We have a HP color printer that can be used to print both A3 and A4 size color printouts. It is connected to a Windows 2008 print server.

The windows event viewer provides the status of printouts using `Event ID 307`. I would like to know if it is possible to find out if an A3 page was printed or A4 page was printed. Is this information also logged in windows event viewer? Or is there any other event id that captures this information?

The number of copies printed should be captured in `Event ID 805`. I have read in some forums that sometimes this value is wrong - is there any truth in this?

Comment: Seems like this would be massively easier to accomplish by checking the logs on the printer itself to see which tray which jobs print from.

Comment: event log does not capture this information, like mentioned check the printer logs